# Drawing a border only on the last item inside my listview

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm trying to create a control like this: [image: FishBone]

The control denotes the status completion of 4 tile objects (in the above attached pic 2 is completed and 2 is not)

For achieving this I have created a ListView with horizontal orientation, and I'm creating a datatemplate which has some borders inside.Not sure whether this is the right approach or whether a simpler approach is possible, however the issue I'm facing is the following:[image]

1. I'm not able to close the border of the last item..this is because I have 4 items inside my itemsource of the listview and each item draws a border to it's left. Question is how do I specifically draw the right border for the last item.
2. The line which passess through the middle should actually go behind the gray shading..how do I achieve that?

Code is as below:

```
        <Style x:Key="FishBoneStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Completed}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGray"/>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,3,-2,3"/>
                </DataTrigger>              
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="FishBoneTemplate">
            <Grid Height="25">
            <Border BorderThickness="1,0,0,0" BorderBrush="Black" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                <Border Style="{StaticResource FishBoneStyle}" x:Name="FishBoneBorder" Width="25">
            </Border>
            </Grid>         
        </DataTemplate>

<!-- The Main Grid-->
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Height="30" Width="130" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
<ListView BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" BorderBrush="Black" ItemsSource="{Binding ProgressTiles}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FishBoneTemplate}">
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
 </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>

<!-- The line which passess through the center-->
  <Border VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="100" Margin="3,0,2,0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"></Border>
</Grid>
```

..and here is the model which is lying inside an observable collection in my viewmodel.There will be always 4 of them.

```
public class ProgressTile : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _completed;
        public bool Completed
        {
            get { return _completed; }
            set
            {
                _completed = value;
                InvokePropertyChanged("Completed");
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void InvokePropertyChanged(string e)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(e));
        }
    }
```

Please can you suggest how to get a look consistent to the attached picture. Also can you please suggest how to solve the issue with drawing a border for the last item and sending the line passing through the middle to background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be done much simpler:

```
<Window x:Class="So17362172FishBoneProgressBar.MainWindow" x:Name="root"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Fish Bone Progress Bar" Height="350" Width="525" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    <Grid Width="100" Height="20">
        <TickBar Fill="Gray" TickFrequency="25" Placement="Top"/>
        <TickBar Fill="Gray" TickFrequency="25" Placement="Bottom"/>
        <Line Stroke="Gray" X1="0" Y1="10" X2="100" Y2="10"/>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tiles, ElementName=root}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="rect" Fill="Gray" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="25" Height="10"/>
                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Completed}" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="rect" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

1. `ListView` is unnecessary. Much simpler `ItemsControl` is enough for this.
2. Ticks can be drawn with `TickBar`. As inner ticks are drawn smaller, two tick bars are put over each other (it shouldn't be an issue, as these are very lightweight).
3. Order of drawing is determined by order in the logical tree. If you want something to be drawn over another, you put it into XAML lower.
4. `Grid` is unnecessary if it contains only one control.